# How to resolve X-Frame-Options header is missing in Angular

Tags: angular, npm

I have an Angular-14 application.

How do I deal with this issue?:

> Missing X-Frame options - X-Frame-Options header is missing or not set to DENY or SAMEORIGIN. Without an X-Frame-Options response header, clickjacking may be possible.

Comment: This header should be set by your HTTP server (Apache ? Nginx ?)

Comment: We need more Info from you here. What is your setup? Is this in the local development environment or using another webserver?

Comment: @Garuno - It is deployed on IIS Server, and it's on Production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a question around IIS. Mircosoft has the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/development/add-http-response-header-web-site?source=recommendations) of adding custom http response headers.
On more Information what the `X-Frame-Options` header is, you can refer to the mozilla [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options):

> The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a <frame>, <iframe>, <embed> or <object>. Sites can use this to avoid click-jacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites.

I would recommend setting the header to `DENY`, if you don't use any of the mentioned tags. If you do the "safe" option for production, that shouldn't break anything in a simple environment is `SAMEORIGIN`. Although this also depends on your application.